# Slidingdrawer toggle icon not visible

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a navigation drawer,Everything working perfectly except the toggle button is not visible.

Here is my Code:

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.list, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility)
```

also added these functions

```
@Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

How can i make it visible?

Comment: what is the api level you are using

Comment: min sdk version 8 and max: 19,I do integrate actionbar scherlock,Everything is fine except this one

Comment: ok.. on which device you are running and what is the version of that device

Comment: Samsung galaxy y(android 2.3) and LG optimus(4.0.3)

Comment: getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

Comment: yup it worked... thanks a lot.. please post it as a answer so that I can upvote and accept the answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we have to enable following method

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);